# How to migrate IDs from JOIN table into foreign key column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables in my PostgreSQL database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "User" (
  id VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "Post" (
  id VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "_PostToUser" (
  "A" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL REFERENCES "Post"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  "B" VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The relationship between `User` and `Post` right now is managed via the `_PostToUser` JOIN table.

However, I want to get rid of this extra JOIN table and simply have a foreign key reference from `Post` to `User`, so I ran this query to create the foreign key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Post" ADD COLUMN "authorId" VARCHAR(25);
ALTER TABLE "Post" 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_author
  FOREIGN KEY ("authorId") 
  REFERENCES "User"("id");
```

Now, I'm wondering what SQL query I need to run in order to *migrate the data* from the JOIN table to the new `authorId` column? If I understand correctly, I need a query that reads all the rows from the `_PostToUser` relation table and for each row:

1. Finds the respective `Post` record by looking up the value from column `A`
2. Inserts the value from column `B` as the value for `authorId` into that `Post` record

**Edit**: As mentioned by @Nick in the comments, I should have clarified that I indeed want to change the relationship from m-n and restrict it to 1-n: *One post can at most have one author. One author/user can write many posts.*

Comment: I don't get it.  If the `_PostToUser` table already contains both the author and post ID values, then why can't you just use that?  Your current design is already optimal by the way, you should not be changing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, right now I need two JOINs in order to get information about a post's author (join `Post` with `_PostToUser` and from there with `User`). According to my understanding, including the FK directly on `Post` would allow me to get the author info with just a single JOIN (from `Post` to `User`). Does that make sense?

Comment: There is most likely no reason to go down this road.  Why do you think you need to do this?  Before giving up on joins, you should first look into the junction table so that lookups can happen faster.  What you are suggesting is non standard practice, and should only be done if there is no other way to work with your current design.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the context. Can you recommend any resources on how lookups in junction tables can be optimized? Also, I'd love any pointers that explain how this is a non standard practice, I'm not a data modeling expert but I thought modeling relationships as FKs would be common practice, so I'd love to learn more about this! :)

Comment: All that aside btw, I'm still interested in what such a data migration query would look like, so I definitely would still appreciate an answer if you have an idea for achieving that!

Comment: You should note that changing your structure as you propose means that you restrict Posts:Authors to an N:1 relationship; i.e. a post cannot have many authors. If that is what you expect for the lifetime of this project, making this change is not an unreasonable thing to do.

Comment: @nick Sorry I should have clarified that in the question already, I indeed want to change to a N:1 relationship (just updated the question to include this info). Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are happy to restrict the relationship between `Posts` and `Users` to `N:1`, and you only store a foreign key to `User` in `Post`, then I think what you are doing is fine. The query to update the `Post` table would be:

```
UPDATE "Post" p
SET "authorId" = pu."B"
FROM "_PostToUser" pu 
WHERE pu."A" = p."id"
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=579d6f1a29f22c2ab579049a360f53b0)

Answer (score 2):

Your current design is already correct, and uses a proper junction table to store the relationships between users and their posts.  In this design, a given relationship only requires storing two ID values, which is lean.  Going in the direction you suggest is denormalizing your data, and will result in data duplication.  To see why this is the case, your suggested table will now store metadata from the author table.  This metadata will, in principle, be repetitive, since a given author's metadata would be the same for every record in the new posts table.

Instead, I suggest indexing the junction table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON "_PostToUser" (B, A);
```

As an example, the above index should help the following query:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*
FROM "User" u
INNER JOIN "_PostToUser" pu ON pu.B = u.id       -- index helps here
INNER JOIN "Post" p ON p.id = pu.A;              -- Post.id is already a primary key
```

The join to the lookup table should now be faster, because Postgres can use the index take a given user `id` value and try to find the corresponding `A` value on the other side of the junction.

Comment: Thanks so much for this context, that's super helpful!!